# python: input for function from command line

Tags: python

i'm currently working on a little command line program that parses the tv program from a website and the user can call different functions on it. i have the functions stored in a dictionary which looks like this:

```
    commands = {"show": show, "show x": showX, "help": TVhelp, "exit": TVexit,
                "actor list": actorList, "actor add x": actorAdd, 
                "actor delete x": actorDel, "recommend": recommend}
```

when the user types any of the keys, the function stored as the value of this key is called. for example show just shows a list of all the programs, help and exit should be self-explaining.

i don't have any problems when calling these functions from the command line with just the bare function name, but the problem is that some of the functions take an extra argument (i called it x here).

when the user for example writes "show 20" the program from the program list with the index 20 should be shown. or when the input is "actor add Arnold Schwarzenegger" the name should be added to a list.

what i want is that the function can be called from the command line with an additional argument and the program recognizes the function name in the input and takes the number or actor name as an argument.

is there a pythonic way to do this with a dictionary?

cheers

Comment: You'll just have to make some decisions about the structure and then enforce them, like "no function key may have spaces" so everything after the first space can be treated as an argument list, for example.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Why can't you just pass the args when you call the function?

Comment: you could split the input text and check the first one or two elements, then pass the remaining elements as arguments to the hashed functions

Comment: ok so my problem is that i can call the function from the command line with "actor add" and he recognizes the function stored in the dict because it's the exact same string. but when i type "actor add name" the function isn't even called because there's an extra argument and the call is not the same as the name stored in the dict. see my problem? i'm sure there's a pretty simple explanation, i'm just fairly new to python.

Comment: Maybe you should just use an actual command line parser for this instead?

Comment: Either do what Two-Bit Alchemist said and don't have spaces in your function keys, or use a separator (eg `=` or `:`) on the command line between the key and its args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily, I suggest you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) for this.  The API is complex but effective.

If you really want to roll your own argument parsing, just pass any additional arguments to the function specified in the dictionary.

```
def zoo_desc(args):
    y = int(args[2])
    describe_me = zoo[y]
    print ('{}, {}'.format(describe_me[0], describe_me[1]))

def zoo_list(args):
    for index, entry in enumerate(zoo):
        print ('{}: {}'.format(index, entry[0]))

handlers = {
        'zoo list': zoo_list, # List the animals in the zoo.
        'zoo desc': zoo_desc  # Describe the indexed animal, aka 'zoo desc x'
        }

zoo = [
('cat', 'a cute feline'),
('mouse', 'a cute rodent'),
('rat', 'an uncute rodent')
]

x = input()
while (x):
    for a in handlers:
        if x.startswith(a):
            handlers[a](x.split()) # When we call a handler, we also pass it the arguments

    x = input()
```

Output:

```
zoo list
0: cat
1: mouse
2: rat
zoo desc 1
mouse, a cute rodent
```